# How do I make a function reference in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an associative array with values that are references to functions.  What is the proper way to do this?  This code works, but gives me a warning.

#### Code

```
<?php

$mergeCodes = array(
    'rev:(\d+)' => reverse_me,
);

$test = "This is a [[rev:1234]] test";

echo "BEFORE: $test\n";
foreach ($mergeCodes as $code => $callback) {
    $code = '\[\[' . $code . '\]\]';
    $test = preg_replace_callback( "/$code/", $callback, $test );
}
echo "AFTER: $test\n";

function reverse_me($input) {
    return strrev($input[1]);
}

?>
```

#### Output

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant reverse_me - assumed 'reverse_me' in /tmp/test2.php on line 4
BEFORE: This is a [[rev:1234]] test
AFTER: This is a 4321 test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, PHP does not have such concept. You're probably confused by JavaScript.

It seems that your final purpose is to make a call to `preg_replace_callback()`. As the name suggests you have to feed it with a callback and that's something pretty simple. All you need is a regular variable that contains one of these:

- A string with a variable name: `'foo'`
- An array with a class name and a method name: `array('Foo', 'doBar')`
- An array with a class instance and a method name: `array($myFoo, 'doBar')`

Find further reference at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.3, you can store anonymous functions ([closures](http://php.net/functions.anonymous)) in variables:

```
$reverse_me = function($input) {
  return strrev($input[1]);
}

$mergeCodes = array(
  'rev:(\d+)' => $reverse_me
);
```

Or you could even do this:

```
$mergeCodes = array(
  'rev:(\d+)' => function($input) {
    return strrev($input[1]);
  }
);
```

See http://php.net/functions.anonymous for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making the value the string `'reverse_me'`.  I guess `$callback` being a string was not very intuitive to me.